# Default custom view settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, custom

Is there a possibility to set some default settings when users are creating their own view? I manually configured the views toolbar as "show toolbar", but if users create a view the default setting "full toolbar" is applied.

When a user creates a view, these default settings should be:

- Toolbar type "show toolbar"
- Misc: Disable view selector menu Misc:
- Disable search box

[image: sharepoint view settings]

Comment: I think you are being taken back to the list itself, not an instance of the list on a page. For example, if I edit the toolbar type on the home page of "List", to be Show Toolbar, and **then** add a view. It will take me to the list as an **app** not the instance of a list on a **page**.

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger what I want is a default setting for all lists views which will be created in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested, you are indeed correct, this does appear to be a bug. However, I would note that the "Show Toolbar" option is the 2007 version of the toolbar and thus, isn't the default. "Full Toolbar" is the 2013 equivalent and appears to reset itself each time you create a view, as you yourself explained. My apologies